# npm ERR! code E404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer 'inquirer@*' is not in this registry.A complete log of this run canbefoundin:

Tags: typescript, http-status-code-404

icrosoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.4123]
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Aliyan_Jabbar\Desktop\Aliyan Jabbar\Aliyan Jabbar IT class\New folder>npm i inquirer
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'inquirer@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Aliyan_Jabbar\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-03-29T23_49_34_595Z-debug-0.log

C:\Users\Aliyan_Jabbar\Desktop\Aliyan Jabbar\Aliyan Jabbar IT class\New folder>

I have changed the registry by a code "npm config set registry [https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer"](https://registry.npmjs.org/inquirer%22)
I have cleared the cache of npm
I have used --force
I have user peer-deps...